How can I mount JSX into my ASP.NET Core MVC Views
I'm building an ASP.NET Core MVC app that also contains a React Vite folder within it.
One of my challenges is to figure out how to dynamically load JSX into a div tag with an id such as in the below example:
Login.cshtml:
@using SphereSocial.Models
@model PageModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@Model.PageName - SphereSocial</title>
    @if (@Model.IsDevelopment)
    {
        <script>
            import React from '~/node_modules/react/index.js';
            import ReactDOM from '~/node_modules/react-dom/index.js';
            import Test from '~/src/Test.jsx';
            ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('loginroot')).render(
                <StrictMode>
                    <Test />
                </StrictMode>,
            );
        </script>
    }
    else
    {
        <script src="~/dist/assets/main.js"></script>
    }
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div id="loginroot"></div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

In the above example, if I'm running npm run dev on my React Vite server, and I hit this View, then the JSX should be mounted in the <div id="loginroot"></div> tag.
Instead of it being mounted within Login.cshtml, it is instead mounted in the entry point of the react app, index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="loginroot"></div>
  </body>
</html>

I want it mounted in my Login.cshtml file.
I understand that I can change the entry point of the React app with any other file such as Login.cshtml, but I don't want a single entry point, I just want to render JSX in specific files.
ChatGPT didn't give me the answer I wanted, said that I can just change the entry point of the React app within vite.config.js.

React is not JSX! JSX is a tool that only HELPS you build your app, it is not even mandatory to use. Browsers don't even understand JSX, it is compiled into regular JS. When you build your react app, it gives you a JS bundle, just include it to your "html" file
